# Evaluación de expresión con varios operadores incremento en C

Tags: c, operador-incremento

Estaba haciendo pruebas con expresiones y me he encontrado con el siguiente ejemplo que no entiendo por qué da el siguiente resultado:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 

int main(void)                                                                     
{                                                                                  
    int n = 0, i;                                                                  

    i = n++ + n++;                                                                 
    printf("n = %d; i = %d\n", n, i);                                                

    return 0;                                                                      
}
```

El resultado que muestra este programa es:

> `n = 2; i = 0`

¿No debería el resultado de `i` ser `1`?

Como el operador incremento tiene mayor precedencia, se realiza antes que la suma. El primer `n++` da como resultado 0 (porque es incremento postfijo), pero `n` pasa a ser `1` tras incrementarse. A continuación se incrementa `n` otra vez, dando el resultado de este segundo operador `1` (vuelve a ser postfijo), e incrementándose `n` a `2`. ¿Por qué no hace esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto:

```
i = n++ + n++;
```

provoca un comportamiento indeterminado porque el estándar no especifica en qué momento se debe evaluar cada post-incremento. Esto provoca que se puedan dar varios resultados posibles:

- opción 1:

  ```
  i = n + n;
  n++;
  n++;
  ```
- opción 2:

  ```
  int temp = n;
  n++;
  i = temp + n;
  n++;
  ```

No suele ser recomendable, por tanto, mezclar incrementos sobre la misma variable dentro de una misma instrucción.

Ahora la respuesta larga:

**C99**

Se define el concepto de *Puntos de secuencia* con una parrafada tal que:

> At certain specified points in the execution sequence called sequence points, all side effects of previous evaluations shall be complete and no side effects of subsequent evaluations shall have taken place.

Que viene a decir que se definen una serie de puntos en los que las expresiones previas deben estar evaluadas. Pasado dicho punto, los valores de las expresiones pasan a ser fijos. Esto implica que entre un punto y otro las expresiones se pueden evaluar en el orden que el compilador considere oportuno.

Vale, ¿y dónde se encuentran esos puntos de secuencia?

> at the end of the evaluation of full expression

Es decir:

- Como norma general, al finalizar una expresión completa:

  ```
  int var = i++; var2 = i++;
  ```

  En este apartado también se incluyen las sentencias `if`, `switch`, `while`, `do-while`, `for` y `return`.
- La evaluación de la primera expresión en los siguientes casos:

  - Operador AND lógico:

    ```
    if( *p++ != 0 && *p++ != 0 )
    ```
  - Operador OR lógico

    ```
    if( *p++ != 0 || *p++ != 0 )
    ```
  - Operador coma (no confundir con su uso como separador):

    ```
    // operador coma
    (a=0, a++, b = a++ ) // ok

    // separador
    func( i, i++, i++); // comportamiento indeterminado
    ```
  - Operador ternario

    ```
    a = (*p++) ? *p++ : 0; // ok
    ```
- En una llamada a función, después de evaluar todos los argumentos.

  ```
  res = f(i++) + g(i++) + h(i++);
  ```
- Entre cada declaración dentro de una secuencia de inicialización:

  ```
  int a = i++, b = i++; // No tiene nada que ver con el operador coma
  ```

**C11**

Esta versión sigue una línea continuísta respecto a su predecesor C99. Eso sí, introduce un nuevo punto de secuencia y modifica el comportamiento del operador ternario:

- Enter la evaluación del primer operando del condicional `?` y también entre la evaluación del segundo y el tercer operando:

  ```
  int b = (a++)? a++ : ++a;
  ```
- Inmediatamente antes e inmediatamente después de cada llamada a una función de comparación así como entre una llamada a una función de comparación y cualquier movimiento de objetos pasados como argumentos

**Versiones anteriores a C++11**

Ahora vamos a saltar al mundo C++. En este caso, para versiones anteriores a C++11 los criteros a aplicar son los mismos que para C99.

**C++11 en adelante**

El caso es que la teoría en este caso se complica porque se añaden conceptos nuevos propios de C++11 así que de momento omitiré esta parte. Además el comportamiento es, en líneas generales, bastante parecido.

Lo más destacable es que con la llegada de C++11 los puntos de secuencia como tal desaparecen y se empieza a hablar de momentos de secuenciado y las relaciones que rigen cada situación.

Así tenemos conceptos como:

- Secuenciado antes
- Secuenciado después
- Sin ordenar
- Secuencia indeterminada

En líneas generales lo mejor es no complicarse la vida tentando a la suerte. Escribir código tal que:

```
i = ++i+i++;
```

Es algo que debería estar penado con multa y cárcel. Me parece perfecto que en un sistema en concreto funcione y que al programador de turno le parezca muy *cool*, pero la triste realidad es que no solo no hay ninguna necesidad de compactar tanto el código sino que además es contraproducente tanto en términos de legibilidad como de portabilidad y mantenimiento.

Comment: Marco la tuya como la válida. Ahora voy a añadir la respuesta que tenía preparada que es bastante parecida a la tuya :). Lo de C11 no lo sabía. ¿Pero es C11 o C++11?

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez respondí a las 2 de la mañana después de estar despierto desde las 6 del día anterior... dejé la respuesta un poco a medias porque literalmente me moría de sueño. Creo con la revisión de hoy está más completa

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias. Las excepciones de los operadores que tienen puntos de secuencia me vienen muy bien. De C++ no sé casi nada, así que respecto a C++11 poco puedo comentar.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de empezar a explicar la causa vamos a describir algunos conceptos en C:

- **Efecto lateral**: una expresión en C tiene efectos laterales cuando modifica el contenido de una variable o archivo.
- **Punto de secuencia**: punto de ejecución del programa en el cual todos los efectos laterales son evaluados antes de ir al siguiente paso. Un punto de secuencia puede ser una sentencia (finalizada con `;`) o una expresión completa (expresión que no forma parte de otra
  expresión mayor).

Es decir, que si la expresión con efecto lateral está dentro de una sentencia o una expresión completa, C asegura que dichos efectos se aplicarán antes de pasar al siguiente paso, pero no define en qué momento se aplican durante la evaluación de la sentencia antes de avanzar a la siguiente.

En el ejemplo expuesto, la sentencia `i = n++ + n++;` asegura que los efectos laterales de la expresión `n++` se van a aplicar antes de avanzar a la siguiente sentencia, pero no define en qué momento de la ejecución de la expresión asignación se aplican. Esto se debe a que `n++` no es una expresión completa (forma parte de una expresión mayor) y por lo tanto no es un punto de secuencia. El punto de secuencia aquí es la sentencia entera finalizada en `;`.

Para obtener el resultado del ejemplo expuesto en la pregunta, el incremento de la variable `n` se realiza una vez finalizada la expresión de asignación. De esta manera se evalúa el primer `n++` (sin aplicar el efecto lateral), se evalúa el segundo `n++` (sin modificar `n` tampoco), se evalúa la asignación y, a continuación, antes de pasar a la siguiente sentencia, se ejecutan los incrementos modificando la variable `n`.

```
i = n++ + n++
i = 0 + 0      // n no se modifica hasta evaluar la asignación
i == 0; n == 2
```

Como alternativa, C también podría haber realizado perfectamente el incremento modificando `n` justo después de evaluar dicho operando `++`, ya que el efecto lateral de modificación de `n` cumpliría perfectamente la restricción de tener que realizarse antes de pasar a la siguiente sentencia:

```
i = n++ + n++
i = 0 + 1      // n se modifica en cada incremento antes de evaluar la asignación.
i == 1; n == 2
```

Hay que recordar y resaltar que **el orden de ejecución de los dos incrementos tampoco está definido** para casos como éste. Es decir, puede evaluarse en primer lugar el segundo incremento y después el primero. Esto se debe a que al evaluar los operadores con la misma precedencia, si no comparten operandos pueden realizarse en el orden que decida la implementación, no estando definido por C. En caso de que los operadores con misma precedencia sí compartan operandos, entonces se evalúan en el orden de asociación dependiente del operador (multiplicación de izqda a dcha, asignación de decha a izqda, etc)

**Resumen:** por lo tanto, siempre que haya una expresión que no sea punto de secuencia en sí mismo y que produzca efectos laterales (`=`, `++`, `--`, etc), el estándar C sólo se asegura que ocurran dichos efectos laterales antes de la finalización del punto de secuencia al cual pertenece la expresión. No se asegura que ocurran en el momento exacto de evaluar la expresión que produce dichos efectos laterales.

*PD: Como bien explica @eferion, se debe evitar poner varias expresiones con efectos laterales que afecten al resultado de la expresión a la que pertenezcan.*